# css for display the 3 div tag in one line

Tags: html, css

I want to display 2 div tag and ul tag list in same line.now It is displayed one by one.(ie.)I want to display menu,social meedia and address in same line.

[image]

```css
.footercolor {
    background: rgba(19, 64, 121, 1);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(19, 64, 121, 1) 0%, rgba(73, 155, 234, 1) 55%, rgba(19, 64, 121, 1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(left top, right top, color-stop(0%, rgba(19, 64, 121, 1)), color-stop(55%, rgba(73, 155, 234, 1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(19, 64, 121, 1)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(19, 64, 121, 1) 0%, rgba(73, 155, 234, 1) 55%, rgba(19, 64, 121, 1) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(19, 64, 121, 1) 0%, rgba(73, 155, 234, 1) 55%, rgba(19, 64, 121, 1) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(19, 64, 121, 1) 0%, rgba(73, 155, 234, 1) 55%, rgba(19, 64, 121, 1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(19, 64, 121, 1) 0%, rgba(73, 155, 234, 1) 55%, rgba(19, 64, 121, 1) 100%);
    filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#134079', endColorstr='#134079', GradientType=1);
 height: 100px;
 padding: 50px 100px 100px;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
}
footer a{
 color: #fff;
}
footer a:hover{
 color: #aaa;
}
.address{
float:right;
}
```

```html
 <footer class="footercolor">
                <div class="down">
                 menu
                </div>
                 <ul class="list-inline ">
  <li><a href=><i class="fa fa-3x fa-facebook-square"></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-3x fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-3x fa-twitter-square"></i></a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="address">
        <p>address</p>
  </div>
    </footer>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
body {
 margin:0;
}
.footercolor {
 background: rgba(19, 64, 121, 1);
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(19, 64, 121, 1) 0%, rgba(73, 155, 234, 1) 55%, rgba(19, 64, 121, 1) 100%);
 background: -webkit-gradient(left top, right top, color-stop(0%, rgba(19, 64, 121, 1)), color-stop(55%, rgba(73, 155, 234, 1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(19, 64, 121, 1)));
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(19, 64, 121, 1) 0%, rgba(73, 155, 234, 1) 55%, rgba(19, 64, 121, 1) 100%);
 background: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(19, 64, 121, 1) 0%, rgba(73, 155, 234, 1) 55%, rgba(19, 64, 121, 1) 100%);
 background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(19, 64, 121, 1) 0%, rgba(73, 155, 234, 1) 55%, rgba(19, 64, 121, 1) 100%);
 background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(19, 64, 121, 1) 0%, rgba(73, 155, 234, 1) 55%, rgba(19, 64, 121, 1) 100%);
 filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#134079', endColorstr='#134079', GradientType=1);
 height:100px;
 padding: 50px 100px 100px;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
}
footer a {
 color: #fff;
}
footer a:hover {
 color: #aaa;
}
.address {
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 float:right;
 display:inline;
}
.address p {
 display:inline;
}
div.down {
 display:inline;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}
ul.list-inline {
 display:inline;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 margin-left:50px;
}
ul.list-inline li {
 display:inline;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}
ul.list-inline li a {
 display:inline;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 text-decoration:none;
}
footer span.copyright {
 width:100%;
 display:inline-block;
 text-align:center;
 padding:10px 0px;
}
```

```html
<footer class="footercolor">
  <div class="down"> menu </div>
  <ul class="list-inline">
    <li><a href=><i class="fa fa-3x fa-facebook-square">f</i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-3x fa-instagram">i</i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-3x fa-twitter-square">t</i></a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="address">
    <p>sample</p>
    <p>demo</p>
    <p>trail</p>
    <br>
    <p>p.7868 </p>
    <p>f.7868 </p>
    <br>
    <p>info@domain.com</p>
  </div>
  <span class="copyright">@ all rights reserved</span> </footer>
```

Comment: Although I have upvoted (since it answers/solves the question), please include an explanation as to *why it does*

Answer (score 1):

Try like this: **[Updated Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/L7uy1ozw/2/)**

CSS:

```
.address {
}
.down, .list-inline, .address {
    display:inline-block;   
    vertical-align:text-top;
    width:30%;
    margin-right:10px;
    background-color:#ccc;
}
ul{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    list-style-position: inside;
}
li{
    padding:10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
display:table-cell
```

for

```
.down, .list-inline, .address
```